# Call to LastDelimiter() won't compile

Tags: delphi

Delphi 7 - if I make a new project and add a line

```
spacePos := LastDelimiter(' ' , 'spaced out');
```

it builds.

If I try to use LastDelimiter in my own project it fails.

I started with a stamenet comparing `LastDelimter(#$D#$A, myString)` and wen that failed I tried with the lien above, which also failed.

I do `use` SysUtils, but that wasn't even necessary when I created a new project.

If I comment out that line my real project builds just fine. If I uncomment it I get "missing operator or semicolon".  Same thing if I move the LastDelimiter to an assignment, even on the fist line of the function which it is in - it really doesn't look like a problem with a previous line.

Any ideas (short of me posting a few klocs)?

Thanks

Comment: Cut the code down to a minimal reproduction. When you do that you'll probably be able to work it out yourself.

Comment: You need to show us the code involving the call to LastDelimiter.

Comment: procedure TForm1.test;
var
  spacePos : Integer;
begin
  spacePos := LastDelimiter(' ', 'position of space');
end; -- Works just fine in a newly created D7 project. No uses added, nothing on the form.

Comment: What happens when you <Ctrl> + Mouse click on LastDelimiter ?

Comment: "Failed" is not a valid Delphi errormessage afaik. What was the Delphi errormessage?

Comment: `Project1.exe raised exception class EMWAHAHAHA with message 'EPIC FAIL'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps somewhere in your scope is a global variable defined similar to the following:

```
var
  LastDelimiter: Integer;
```

Check the units used in your project. It should be a global variable declared in the interface section.

Or it could be a constant, declared in the interface section, similar to this:

```
const
  LastDelimiter = 32;
```

Comment: d'oh !! how coudl I be so dumb (and not spot it) ?

Answer (score 4):

You have learned what a namespace or identifier or "scope collision" is, today.  Some unit in your implementation or interface uses clause, also defines LastDelimiter, and since it is the innermost or most recent declaration, it renders that particular identifier in SysUtils invisible until you specify the SysUtils prefix.

When you have namespace collisions, you should qualify the function name with its unit name, and it will then compile for you:

```
  x := SysUtils.LastDelimiter( .... );
```

For this very reason, some developers who are comfortable with languages like C# and Java are used to always requiring namespaces to be specified, thus their code looks like this:

```
 x := namespace.Thing1.Thing2.GetInput( ... );
```

Just because we don't always do that in Delphi doesn't mean there aren't times when you SHOULD be doing that.